# Understanding how to create an object inside an if statement condition

Tags: java, instanceof

I was asking my colleague about some ideas on tidying up some code I had written, and he had provided me with a pattern that looks like this:

```
if (obj instanceof SomeClass<?> newObj) {
    if (newObj.bar()) {
        foo();
    }
}
```

I had no idea that you can instantiate an object (**newObj**) inside the if statement condition itself. I've tried googling and searching on SO for an answer but have come up empty. Can someone please explain to me how this works?

Comment: Looks like it was introduced in JDK15 - `newObj` is the binding variable and is assigned the `obj` being tested if the `instanceof` operator evaluates to true: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/language/pattern-matching-instanceof-operator.html.  Essentially it is shorthand for `if (obj instanceof SomeClass<?>) { SomeClass<?> newObj = (SomeClass<?>) obj; ... }`

Comment: You're not 'creating a new object' - there is only one object.   You have a new variable, of a different type, that refers to the one and only object.  The difference between variables and objects is essential to understand.

Comment: @user16632363 forgive my terminology, I wasn't sure what the Java code was doing. So it's a variable that's casting the object into a different type?

Comment: As @Andy wrote in his comment (which could be posted as an answer), it's a shorthand for what previously required a separate variable declaration and cast.

Comment: @Delibrete - you don't need my forgiveness :-)

Comment: Thanks @Andy for answering the question :) Shame I can't mark this question as solved.